# wordpress urls not working with apache virtualhost

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have setup a apache virtual host using the below script -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName nvoids.cu.cc
    ServerAlias www.nvoids.cu.cc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now this is working fine at this url - http://nvoids.cu.cc 
which serves the pages from **/var/www/html/blog**

But the wordpress permalinks are not working for example

http://nvoids.cu.cc/hello/ throws a 404 page.

For that i tried changing the .htaccess file as follows -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase blog/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
AllowOverride All
```

In your VirtualHost directive to enable use of .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Is the following module enabled in your php.ini which should be uncommented? Do you see any error in your apache error log file?

```
LoadModule rewrite_module
```

Comment: rewrite module is working fine. It is working in other cases. I have used a2enmod rewrite to install that.

Comment: just an idea, if your document root includes blog, do you need really rewritebase blog/? i dont think so. (i forget the apache commands since i dont use them everyday) :)

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Daniel the virtual server conf should be -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName nvoids.cu.cc
    ServerAlias www.nvoids.cu.cc
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/blog
        <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
     <Directory /var/www/html/blog/>

        AllowOverride All

        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file as it is modified by wordpress -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```